# Better name for a square prism

Tags: single-word-requests, names

What is the proper name for a cube which is stretched in one direction. So that it is really four rectangles of the same size with two squares at the ends.

Elongated/stretched cube? Rectangular/square prism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because all the angles are right angles, it's a cuboid.
Because it has the same cross-section along its length, it's a prism.
Because all the faces are rectangles of one sort or another, it's a rectangular prism.
Because two opposite faces are squares, it's a **square prism.**
Because all faces are not the same size, it's not a cube.

Reference: [Maths is fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/cuboids-rectangular-prisms.html)

A prism where two opposite sides are triangles is called a triangular prism. What a prism is called is determined by the faces which are not rectangles.